# Can I Watermark An Image With Its Filename and Copy name when exporting from Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, printing, prints, filenames, watermark

I'd like to send a variety of versions of the same image to a lab to look at differences in stock, contrast and sharpening. I know I'll be able to tell the difference in stock by the information on the back of the print, but I need a way to tell the difference between a number of quite subtle variations in image on the same stock.

As these images are for my own testing purposes alone, the most useful way I can think of would be to have the name of the image added in text to each Virtual Copy as a watermark. So Ideally each image would have a watermark made up of:

{image name} {copy name}

Looking at Lightroom CC's watermarking features, I can't see a way to dynamically generate the text from the Virtual Copy's filename and copy name.

What is the best way for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a 3rd party plug-in like [LR Mogrify 2](http://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/lrmogrify2.php). Despite the text on its homepage, it is compatible with current versions of Lightroom.

Comment: Thanks. I'd looked at that, but it appears to be for Lightroom 2

Comment: It does actually support Lightroom 2 upwards, though this isn's clear from the site.

Comment: @Pedr Yes! Sorry I saw your comment just now, I can confirm that it is compatible with Lr CC 2015.

Comment: Just downloaded, and bought a license for this.
Worked flawlessly in Lightroom Classic CC 2019.
Put filename right on the image.